# How to make html website make POST and GET requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, express

I want to have a simple website be able to send and receive data from a server. As for the server, it will be a javascript express server using MongoDB and Mongoose.

What would be the best way to make a POST and GET requests to the server from the client side website. Note that I would prefer not to use forms. Would I be able to receive a value from the user, and then upon pressing a button, call a javascript script to post the data to the server? This is the first time I'm making something like this so please keep your answers as dumbed down/ explained as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and actually not very difficult. You can either use something like angular.js to control your front-end and use that to send your requests Or What I would recommend is using jquery ajax to send POST and GET requests.

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST", // Type of Request
  url: url, // Url to Post to
  data: data, // What you are send. Not applicable for GET Requests
  success: function(success){
  // Enter code after scucess of request
 },
  dataType: dataType // Type of Data you are sending. Would recommend JSON.
});
```

[Jquery Ajax Post Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python then try Flask web app Its easy and best Im also using this

**install flask**

```
pip install flask
```

**Form in Html**

```
<form action='/adduser'>
<input type='text' name='q'></input>
<button type='submit'></button>
</form>
```

**In python terminal**

```
from flask import request , Flask,  Markup
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/adduser')
def adduser():
 user = request.args.get('q')
 import os
 os.system('echo "%s" > log.txt' % user)
 #adding user detail for log.txt
 html = '<p> Hello %s </p>' % user
 html = Markup(html)
 return html
app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port='8000')
```

Comment: I think the OP was asking for it in jquery

Answer (score 0):

You could interact with server in a RESTful manner, where the server will act as REST API and client will send GET, POST requests to fetch or send data. Potential approaches you could use are `jquery` AJAX calls, `axios` package, `fetch` API. 
It could be said to go with `fetch` API since it's HTML5 feature: [FETCH API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). It will not require any external package such as `axios`, or force you to use `jquery` if you're working with different framework. However go for `axios` if you need advanced features for your use case.

Another approach for communication between client and server is to use **s** connections. Since you're using NodeJS server, you could go with `socket.io`. This will unable you unidirectional real-time data flow. Simply server could push any thing if there's any update, rather than client continously checking for server updates. Look here for [SocketIO](https://socket.io)